# Как записать в файл?

Tags: c++, файлы

Как записать массив чисел в файл?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
  float arr[10];
  //initialise array;
  ofstream out ("test.txt", ios::app);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    out << arr[i] << endl;
  out.close();
}
```

Вроде так. Проверь

Comment: я просто не успел еще после установки винды поставить компилятор